# UICollectionView reloads data without calling reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have structured my app using the MVVM pattern, the `datasource` of the `collectionView` gets data from the `viewModel`. 
In `viewModel` I have a closure which gets called after updating the data, it passes `IndexSet` of sections and `[IndexPath]` of items which `collectionView` should insert. However I get the crash everytime after calling the insert method with error:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (11) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (11), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (11 inserted, 0 deleted).'

I understand what this error means, however I noticed that this is the order in which the methods are called

```
 1. viewDidLoad()

 2.  numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) // returns 0

 3.   update?(insertedSectionsSet, insertedRows) // the closure gets called in viewModel, insertedSectionsSet has 11 elements, that's correct

 4.   numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) // returns 11, that's correct but it should be called after next point

 5.   viewModel.update = { [weak self] sections, items in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                        self?.collectionView.insertSections(sections) // crash
                        self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: items)
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

As you can see in the code below, I added prints before calling each methods and you can clearly see that numberOfSections gets called after calling the closure and before performing it. It makes absolutely no sense to me why is it happening. I believe that the cause of crash lies in calling the numberOfSections before inserting them, because then it expects 22 sections after inserting.

> update
>
> numberofsections
>
> closure
>
> numberofsections

Code:

```
class PlaylistsDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    ...

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        print("numberofsections")
        return viewModel.numberOfSections
    }

    ...
}

class PlaylistsMasterViewController: UIViewController {

 ...
 viewDidLoad() {
   viewModel.update = { [weak self] sections, items in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("closure")
                self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    self?.collectionView.insertSections(sections)
                    self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: items)
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
 }
 ...
}

class PlaylistsMasterViewModel {

private var sectionIndexes = [String]()
private var playlistsDictionary = [String: [AWPlaylist]]()
var update: ((IndexSet, [IndexPath]) -> Void)?

var numberOfSections: Int {
    return sectionIndexes.count
}
```

EDIT: Added more code

```
extension PlaylistsMasterViewModel {

func fetchPlaylists() {
    repo.getAllPlaylists(from: [.iTunes]) { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let playlists):
            self?.sortIncoming(playlists: playlists)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

private func sortIncoming(playlists: [AWPlaylist]) {

    var insertedPlaylists = [(key: String, list: AWPlaylist)]()
    var insertedIndexes = [String]()

    func insertNewSection(playlist: AWPlaylist, key: String) {
        insertedIndexes.append(key)
        playlistsDictionary.updateValue([playlist], forKey: key)
    }

    func insertNewRow(playlist: AWPlaylist, key: String) {
        guard var value = playlistsDictionary[key] else {
            print("Oh shit")
            return
        }
        value.append(playlist)
        value.sort(by: SortingPredicates.Playlist.nameAscending)
        playlistsDictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        insertedPlaylists.append((key, playlist))
    }

    for list in playlists {
        let name = list.localizedName.uppercased().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        guard let firstCharacter = name.first else { return }
        let firstLetter = String(firstCharacter)
        let key: String
        if CharacterSet.english.contains(firstLetter.unicodeScalars.first!) {
            key = firstLetter
        } else if CharacterSet.numbers.contains(firstLetter.unicodeScalars.first!) {
            key = "#"
        } else {
            key = "?"
        }
        if playlistsDictionary[key] == nil {
            insertNewSection(playlist: list, key: key)
        } else {
            insertNewRow(playlist: list, key: key)
        }
    }

    sectionIndexes.append(contentsOf: insertedIndexes)
    sectionIndexes.sort(by: { $0 < $1 })
    let insertedSections = insertedIndexes.compactMap { index -> Int? in
        guard let sectionIndex = self.sectionIndexes.firstIndex(of: index) else {
            return nil
        }
        return sectionIndex
    }
    let insertedSectionsSet = IndexSet(insertedSections)

    let insertedRows = insertedPlaylists.compactMap { tuple -> IndexPath? in
        if let section = self.sectionIndexes.firstIndex(of: tuple.key) {
            if let row = self.playlistsDictionary[tuple.key]?.firstIndex(where: { $0.equals(tuple.list) }) {
                return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    print("update")
    update?(insertedSectionsSet, insertedRows)
```

}

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `numberOfSections` to determine why it is being called.  It seems that it is being called once when you have added the items to the viewModel array but before you have inserted the sections and then again after you have inserted the sections.  Showing more view model code would probably help us help you

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added more code. Please take a look at the Edit2

Comment: I think your problem is that `viewModel.numberOfSections` returns 11 before you have called the `update` closure, which means that you have an inconsistency when you insert the sections. `numberOfSections` can be called at any time and must return a value consistent with other operations you are planning on the collection view. I must say that personally I don't think that the MVVM architecture is a good fit for iOS development unless you use a 3rd party binding framework. MVVM came from Windows where controls support binding "out of the box".

Comment: You haven't shown the code for `viewModel.numberOfSections` but one way that I can see this working is if you call the `update` closure each time you add a section or a row rather than batching updates.  Alternatively you would need to hold updates to the viewModel properties in temporary properties and only commit those changes immediately prior to calling the `update` closure. To avoid race conditions, the view model should dispatch a block on the main queue that updates the viewModel properties and calls the `update` closure